# awk: arithmetic does not work on a particular field

Tags: awk, arithmetic

I have several lines such as:

```
N2O       + M       = N2       + O     + M          1.300E+11  0.00  59620.0
```

I need to substitute the third from last field with a factor of itself which does not work with `awk`. However, if I apply the same expression on the last field or even second from last field it works. I tested separately with the scientific notation and `awk`, it works. Examples below:

```
#works as expected; last field gets multiplied by -1
echo "N2O       + M       = N2       + O     + M          1.300E+11  0.00  59620.0" | awk '{gsub($(NF),-1.0*$(NF))};{print}'
N2O       + M       = N2       + O     + M          1.300E+11  0.00  -59620

#does not work; third from last field stays unchanged
echo "N2O       + M       = N2       + O     + M          1.300E+11  0.00  59620.0" | awk '{gsub($(NF-2),-1.0*$(NF-2))};{print}'
N2O       + M       = N2       + O     + M          1.300E+11  0.00  59620.0
```

Any suggestions as to why is this happening?

Comment: `gsub` is meant for regex replacements on strings. You really need `awk '{$(NF-2)*=-1; print}'`

Comment: @1_CR thanks, this works. May be add this as an answer. I am losing the scientific notation in the result. Do you know how could I preserve it?

Comment: look up `awk`'s `printf` for scientific notation

Answer (score 1):

The answer can be found in **man awk**:

> A numeric expression  is  converted  to string by replacing *expr* with `sprintf(CONVFMT, expr)`, unless *expr* can be represented on the host machine as an exact integer then it is converted to `sprintf("%d", expr)`.
>   *Sprintf()* is  an AWK built-in that duplicates the functionality of `sprintf(3)`, and *CONVFMT* is a built-in variable
>          used for internal conversion from number to string and initialized to `"%.6g"`.

So while you call `gsub` function which operates with string **awk** has convert field by `sprintf("%d", 1.300E+11)` into `130000000000` but there is no such text in the line so nothing to replace.